# Java RenderedImage implementation with custom raw DataBuffer

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I receive 16-bit grayscale images from a device, the images are delivered in an uncompressed raw format
, here is a 8 bytes example of how 2X2 image will look like using this format (MSB first) :

```
21 27           33 F6          28 F3           27 F2
-----           -----          -----           -----
pixel 0,0(x,y)  pixel 1,0      pixel 1,0       pixel 1,1
```

I need to compress the images using Kakadu JPEG2000 library that expose a Java 
ImageWriter implementation, the ImageWriter.write method expect a RenderedImage as input, I'm using the following code to create a BufferedImage from the raw image data :

```
int[] rasterData = new int[width * height];
int rawBufferOffset = 0;
for(int i=0;i<rasterData.length;i++) {
   rasterData[i] = ((int) rawBuffer[rawBufferOffset + 1] << 8) | ((int) rawBuffer[rawBufferOffset] & 0xFF);
   rawBufferOffset += 2;
}
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width,   height,BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
image.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, width, height, rasterData);
```

The code works but it's obviously not the best method to this conversion,
I was thinking about creating a RenderedImage implementation that uses the rawBuffer as the image raster data source, can anyone suggest how to do so or suggest any other method for this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way, is probably to use a `ByteBuffer` to swap the byte order, and create a new `short` array to hold the pixel data.

Then wrap the (`short`) pixel data in a  `DataBufferUShort`. Create a matching `WritableRaster` and `ColorModel`, and finally create a `BufferedImage` from this. This image should be identical to the image in your code above (`BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`), but be slightly faster to create, as you only copy the pixels once (as opposed to twice in your code).

```
int w = 2;
int h = 2;
int stride = 1;

byte[] rawBytes = {0x21, 0x27, 0x33, (byte) 0xF6, 0x28, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0xF2};
short[] rawShorts = new short[rawBytes.length / 2];

ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .asShortBuffer()
        .get(rawShorts);

DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferUShort(rawShorts, rawShorts.length);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(dataBuffer, w, h, w * stride, stride, new int[]{0}, null);
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

Another, slightly more convoluted, but probably faster way (as you don't copy the backing pixel array at all), is to create a custom `SampleModel` that works with MSB (little endian) byte data, but exposes them as `TYPE_USHORT`. This will create a `TYPE_CUSTOM` image.

```
int w = 2, h = 2, stride = 2;
byte[] rawBytes = {0x21, 0x27, 0x33, (byte) 0xF6, 0x28, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0xF2};
DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(rawBytes, rawBytes.length);

SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT, w, h, stride, w * stride, new int[] {0}) {
    @Override
    public Object getDataElements(int x, int y, Object obj, DataBuffer data) {
        if ((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= width) || (y >= height)) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Coordinate out of bounds!");
        }

        // Simplified, as we only support TYPE_USHORT
        int numDataElems = getNumDataElements();
        int pixelOffset = y * scanlineStride + x * pixelStride;

        short[] sdata;

        if (obj == null) {
            sdata = new short[numDataElems];
        }
        else {
            sdata = (short[]) obj;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numDataElems; i++) {
            sdata[i] = (short) (data.getElem(bankIndices[i], pixelOffset + bandOffsets[i] + 1) << 8|
                    data.getElem(bankIndices[i], pixelOffset + bandOffsets[i]));
        }

        return sdata;
    }
};
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, null);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

I don't really see a reason for creating a `RenderedImage` subclass for this.

Comment: This is awesome, the non copying code reduced my JVM memory consumption to almost nothing, thank you!